# Wordpress: Use set_query_var in function multiple times on a post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my WordPress theme, one of my short codes calls a function that uses set_query_var. I don't understand the scope. Is it ok to use that short code more than once in a post? Is that use of set_query_var local to the short code? Because it passes to other theme parts, I think it must be global. Example:

```
function my_func ($atts) {
     var $the_amount = $atts['amount']; //passed from the short code
     set_query_var('my_amount', $the_amount);
}
```

Using the short code that calls this function more than once in a post seems to work ok, but I don't know if this is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `set_query_var` is not local. The value is set globally.

Yes, it is allowed to use it multiple times on the same variable - however note that it will reset the value *each time*, so make sure you are finished with the previous value before resetting it.

But as long as your shortcode is well written, it should be ok.

Note that the reason it is used (even though passing information through global variables are bad practice) is because it is currently the only way to pass variables to other template parts. However the **next release of WP (v5.5) will *at last* offer a way to pass variables between template files**, and once that version is widely used that is the better, cleaner way to pass information between template files.

[Passing arguments to template files in WordPress 5.5](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/17/passing-arguments-to-template-files-in-wordpress-5-5/)

Comment: Wow! WordPress 5.5 sounds like it will make my life easier. I look forward to it. Thank you for your time.